# how to update javascript variable array from c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

am working with this array in javascript of marks to show all marks in the map  as static  work is perfect

```
 var markers = [
{
    "title": 'Aksa Beach',
    "lat": '31.6227697895779',
    "lng": '-4.998779296875',
    "description": '/www.google.com">Read more</a>'
}];
```

but  if i can add some marks from model in html view is my problem

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    markers.push({
    "title": item.name,
    "lat": item.lat,
    "lng": item.long,
    "description": item.descript
});
}
```

Comment: I think that serializing objects to JSON is a better way of creating complex data for JS than manually creating them.

Comment: am not familiar with json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the values with single or double quotes. Also since `item` is a C# variable, you need to use `@`. You also need to use `<text>` tag as you are mixing C# code and plain text (js code)

```
<script>
  var markers = [];
  @foreach (var item in Model) {

   <text>
        markers.push({  "title": "@item.name",
                         "lat": "@item.lat",
                         "lng": "@item.long",
                         "description":"@item.descript"
                   });
   </text>

  }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you your answer open my mind but my map is gone

Comment: May be the lat and long values from your Model collection is not valid. Do a `console.log(markers)` after the loop and confirm whether that is the expected values